# Copy database offline mode

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been using SMO for a while for transfering databases. It was pretty easy to handle from c# by using the TransferDatabase task.

For my current project this gets to slow. I have to switch to offline mode, where the database is detached and atached.

What is the least troublesome way to start such a process from c#? I know that there is SSIS, but if possible I would not like to use it. Installing SSIS on my machine is a bit painfull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just issue the SQL Server Detach and Attach command from c#

Something like this...

```
var sourceConnectionString = "Data Source=sourceServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;";
var destinationConnectionString = "Data Source=destinationServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;";

var sourceLocalPath = @"C:\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf";
var destinationLocalPath = @"C:\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf";

var sourceRemotePath = @"\\ServerNameA\ShareName\MyDB.mdf";
var destinationRemotePath = @"\\ServerNameB\ShareName\MyDB.mdf";

// Make connections
var sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceConnectionString);
sourceConnection.Open();
var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString);
destinationConnection.Open();

// Detach source database
var sourceCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_detach_db MyDB", sourceConnection);
sourceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Detach destination database
var destinationCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_detach_db MyDB", destinationConnection);
destinationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Copy database file
File.Copy(sourceRemotePath, destinationRemotePath);

// Re-attach source database
sourceCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE MyDbName ON (FILENAME = '" + sourceLocalPath + "') FOR ATTACH", sourceConnection);
sourceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Re-attach destination database
destinationCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE MyDbName ON (FILENAME = '" + destinationLocalPath + "') FOR ATTACH", destinationConnection);
destinationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This looks fine. I just have  wierd problem when I run code that seams to the same like this 2 times. The newly attached DB can not be accessed in the same process then. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350656

Comment: @Malcolm Frexner: Attach is a pretty hefty command, so it could cause problems. You could use a separate connection just for this command. The only way I know of to do this in SQL Server is connect using different credentials. Also check the credentials don't have default database set to attached DB, this can cause problems too

Comment: At the end it turned out to be a problem cuased by connection pooling. I switched off connection pooling and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

I do this work in my project.
you can use `SqlBulkCopy` class in C#. this class is very powerful and you can copy all of data with best performance.
this class make a bcp command and run it on your server. this commands are like this:

```
bcp pubs.dbo.authors out c: emppubauthors.bcp –n –Sstevenw –Usa –P
bcp pubs2.dbo.authors in c: emppubauthors.bcp –n –Sstevenw –Usa –P
```

there is many switches for this command. please see this code:

```
// Create source connection
SqlConnection source = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
// Create destination connection
SqlConnection destination = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

// Clean up destination table. Your destination database must have the
// table with schema which you are copying data to.
// Before executing this code, you must create a table BulkDataTable
// in your database where you are trying to copy data to.

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM BulkDataTable", destination);
// Open source and destination connections.
source.Open();
destination.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// Select data from Products table
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", source);
// Execute reader
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Create SqlBulkCopy
SqlBulkCopy bulkData = new SqlBulkCopy(destination);
// Set destination table name
bulkData.DestinationTableName = "BulkDataTable";
// Write data
bulkData.WriteToServer(reader);
// Close objects
bulkData.Close();
destination.Close();
source.Close();
```